# When should I request a new offer letter?

Tags: offer

I was hired after I signed and returned an offering letter. Then I was laid off for the winter.  Then in spring I was offered my job back.  The company was in court and changed hands while I was unemployed.  Do I need another offer letter, should I ask for one?

Comment: When you say "laid off" do you mean your employment was terminated, or were you temporarily laid off?

Answer (score 10):

You need to know, in writing, the terms of the offer -- salary and start date and start location at a minimum, preferably some indication of what the benefits package will be. Anything else you consider a requirement before you'll accept the job.

You *can* wait and get all of that on your first day of work, but that holds you up from applying elsewhere, and there is always the risk that you won't like the offer and will walk out without a job.

An offer letter is usually where all of this gets stated. General advice us that until you have a signed offer letter in your hand you don't have a reliable offer. Ask them to put it in writing.